# In Android framework service modify /data/data/ directory

Tags: android

I have created a very simple service in Android framework ( I am modifying the android framework and adding a custom api.)

For some reason this service is not able to modify or even list down all the folders in the /data/data folder. Below am simply trying to rename the app folder name.

For e.g.

```
  public void moveData(String dataLocation,int uId){
    File dir = new File(dataLocation);
    File newName = new File(dataLocation+"_"+uId);


    bool = dir.renameTo(newName);  

    Log.i("File renamed ?",""+bool);     //this gives false. Why is that ?
}
```

I thought system framework services have root privilege by default. Can I assign it root privileges ?

Comment: What version of android are you using? The new Android has changed writing permissions. Please read the documentation on this, it will probably help.

Comment: Android is designed to have as little as possible run as root.  A fair amount of framework code actually executes in the process of apps, as their unprivileged users, while other parts (on the far side of an IPC call) execute as semi-privileged system users.  Renaming an app's data folder is a first class bad idea.

Comment: @ChrisStratton this is a research project that we are working on. We want to execute these commands. Can you please tell us if there is a way to do this ?

Comment: "research" is not an excuse for bad ideas, or to put it another way, the first thing you need to "research" is how the system you hope to modify is *intended* to work.  Once you have done that, you will realize you need to rethink your plans, as there is no logic to them.